# Does base class gets instantiated for every new instance?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clr

I have been thinking about how the CLR creates new instances. Consider this code:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base()
    { }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived()
        : base()
    { }
}
```

These are my questions:

1. Does an `System.Object` instance get created every time for this line of code, `var baseObj = new Base();`? How many instances are there in memory? Is it 2 or 1?
2. For this line of code: `var derObj = new Derived();`. How many instances will be created? Is it 3 or 2?

Comment: 1 and 1 respectively. A `Derived` instance *is a* `Base` instance, on its own, a `Base` instance *is a*n `Object`.

Comment: Only one instance; which will have all the fields and methods of its base class hierarchy in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both samples, there is just one object. There is just one piece of memory allocated and the base class 'merges' with its parents. There is just one class containing all the methods, fields and properties that are derived from the base classes, including the base-class-of-all. `object`.

What would you think will happen if `var derivedObj = new Derived();` creates two instances? How to refer to the one that is not assigned to `baseObj`? There is no use in keeping two instances of the classes alive. Just one will do.

Comment: I think you're partly correct. I'd assume that there is one **Managed** System.Object instance in memory and there are two instances of System.Object one for each Base and Derived_on the heap_. A corresponding symbol reference would be maintained on the _stack_ for both **Base** and **Derived**

Comment: Also note that this explanation is not specific to C#, but is true of object oriented languages in general.